# Export to CSV is putting all HTML at the bottom of the file

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo, export

I am using a script to export a mysql database to a .csv file but its also including all the html for the page underneath the exported file.

```
$fields = array();
    $csv = array();
    /*** mysql hostname ***/
    $hostname = DB_HOST;
    $dbname = DB_NAME;
    /*** mysql username ***/
    $username = DB_USER;
    /*** mysql password ***/
    $password = DB_PASS;
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $tablename = 'comments';
        $sql = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM `'.$tablename.'`';

        $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            array_push($fields, $row['Field']);
        }

        array_push($csv, $fields);
        $sql = 'SELECT `name`,`comment`,`email` FROM `'.$tablename.'`';

        $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        $csv = array();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
        {
            array_push($csv, $row);
        }

        $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

        foreach ($csv as $row) {
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }

        fclose($fp);
        header("Content-type: application/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=comments.csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        readfile('file.csv');
        $dbh = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

If anyone knows how to rectify this it would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: How do you call this code? Is the the snippet truncated?

Comment: when I test your code, the csv doesn't contain html

Comment: another thing you have comments.csv` as a filename in your attachment

Comment: @NicolasPerraut No its not, I call it with a $_GET request and it fires automatically.

Comment: @julekgwa This is so I can download the file immediately after its generated.

I get all the rows back fine but I also get the source. I've never seen that happen before.

Comment: why not `file.csv`?

Comment: @julekgwa There would be multiple downloads available on this page so I need to way for the user to know which is which

Answer (score 0):

Seems an

```
exit;
```

After the script has stopped any HTML being entered into the .csv